# Iteration over array of primitives using <ui:repeat>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, primitive-types, uirepeat

Documentation of [ui:repeat](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html), attribute `value` states that it can iterate over

> List, array, java.sql.ResultSet, or an individual java Object

However it seems that `int[]` is understood as `Object` rather than array. **Is that any way how to iterate over array of primitives in JSF 2.2?** Or at least why it is not possible?

My code:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class UiRepeatBean {

    public int[] getArray() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 4)
                .toArray();
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return IntStream.of(getArray())
                .mapToObj(i -> i)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Integer[] getArrayOfIntegers() {
        return IntStream.of(getArray())
                .mapToObj(i -> i)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <head>
        <title>Start Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <h:body>
        <p>
            int[]
            <ui:repeat value="#{uiRepeatBean.array}" var="i">
                #{i}
            </ui:repeat>
        </p>
        <p>
            List&lt;Integer>
            <ui:repeat value="#{uiRepeatBean.list}" var="i">
                #{i}
            </ui:repeat>
        </p>
        <p>
            Integer[]
            <ui:repeat value="#{uiRepeatBean.arrayOfIntegers}" var="i">
                #{i}
            </ui:repeat>
        </p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

rendered result:

```
int[] [I@70fcfc34
List<Integer> 0 1 2 3
Integer[] 0 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because an array of primitives cannot be cast to `Object[]` as required by underlying [`ArrayDataModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/model/ArrayDataModel.html). An array of primitives is an instance of `Object` instead of `Object[]`. There is no way to convert an array of primitives to `Object[]` other than looping over it and creating a new array. This isn't really the responsibility of a model view presenter framework like JSF. The developer itself is responsible for supplying the right model in first place.

I however do agree that the documentation can be more clarified on this. You can do that by leaving an issue at [JSF spec](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC) guys.